# Jenkins with Subversion

Tags: svn, jenkins, hudson, maven-release-plugin, svnkit

```
/bin/sh: svn: command not found
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: Unable to check for local modifications
Provider message:
The svn command failed.
```

Jenkins could not find Subversion even though the "Subversion Plugin" is already installed.

Answer (score 11):

The reason for this error is that you have to define explicitly in the pom.xml that the maven-release-plugin should use svnkit.

Here's how:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <goals>clean install</goals>
                <providerImplementations>
                    <svn>javasvn</svn>
                </providerImplementations>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.google.code.maven-scm-provider-svnjava</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-scm-provider-svnjava</artifactId>
                    <version>2.0.5</version>
                    <scope>compile</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to install subversion in your machine. If your OS is Centos you can run

`yum install subversion`