# M2 Release Plugin +Jenkins +Subversion

Tags: maven, svn, jenkins

I have a Jenkins v1.553, Subversion Plugin v2.4 and M2 Release Plugin 0.14 installed.

My problem is that m2 try to execute svn from PATH not from Subversion Plugin. The result is :

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5:prepare (default-cli) on project test: Unable to check for local modifications
[ERROR] Provider message:
[ERROR] The svn command failed.
[ERROR] Command output:
[ERROR] /bin/sh: svn: command not found
```

Is there an option somewhere to specify using Subversion plugin ?

Thanks

Comment: You need to install SVN command line client as the message `/bin/sh: svn: command not found` implies.

Comment: @khmarbaise : thanks for your answer.Of course I know that I can install a subversion command line client, but it's not my desire here. What is the purpose of a SVN plugin, if I need to install a SVN client on the server ? :/

Comment: I know I can use a specific `providerImplementations` in the pom.xml for the maven-release-plugin but I must specify, again, the SVN credentials whereas subversion plugin knows it.

Comment: The credentials must be put into the settings.xml file.

Comment: @Cyril Have you checked this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16897288/jenkins-with-subversion ?